# Apply a border-bottom with a css transition on link-hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'd like a dotted line to be displayed (with a smooth transition) on link-hover. I tried the below, without success. What is the issue?
Many thanks,

See http://jsfiddle.net/94w8xb3a/1/

```
 article p {
    margin-bottom: 1.1em;
    font-size: 16px;
}

article a:link, article a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9EB63C;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition:border-bottom .5s;
    -moz-transition:border-bottom .5s;
    -ms-transition:border-bottom .5s;
     -o-transition:border-bottom .5s;
        transition:border-bottom .5s;
}

article a:hover, {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9EB63C;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #10425E;
   -webkit-transition:border-bottom .5s;
    -moz-transition:border-bottom .5s;
    -ms-transition:border-bottom .5s;
     -o-transition:border-bottom .5s;
        transition:border-bottom .5s;

}
```

Comment: Weird, that's strange.  I can't seem to fix it no matter what I tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple syntax problem. Remove comma in this rule:

```
article a:hover, {
               ^--- remove this comma
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/94w8xb3a/2/

Comment: Oh wow, such a small error.  They should really make it so CSS errors log in the console.

Comment: Well CSS doesn't throw errors. However IDE's should normally warn you about such flaws.

Comment: Thanks, very good spot! That said, the smooth transition doesn't seem to be applied. Would you know why?

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/94w8xb3a/4/ You need to set `border-bottom` initially (for example transparent). You also don't need transition rules on `:hover`. Plus no need of all vendor prefixes, support for transitions is pretty [good](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition).

Answer (score 3):

The browser does not apply the transition for a mere syntax error:

There is a comma in `article a:hover, {`.

Remove it and the transition will be applied (but the user will not spot the difference).

To solve this mystery you have to know what are the properties that support animations. As a reference, I usually use the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties).

You will discover that the `border-bottom` property is affected for width and color. The width of 1px in your css is too thin as the range will vary from 0 to 1.

The color is a better solution, but you have to specify the initial state in the 
`article a:link, article a:visited` rule by adding one of the following properties
(or a similar one):

```
border-bottom: 1px dotted transparent;
```

or

```
border-bottom: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;
```